# rtoday() ESQL function for Perl?

Tags: perl, date, unix, informix

I am currently re-writing an Informix ESQL/C program into Perl. One of the issues that I come across is trying to get the exact same value as from `rtoday()` in Perl.

After looking at the doc from IBM:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/sii-xbrstod-41016.htm%23sii-xbrstod-41016

```
"today
A pointer to an int4 value that receives the internal DATE.
Usage
The rtoday() function obtains the system date on the client computer, not 
the server computer."
```

When doing echo $DATE on the command line, I get:

```
username@myServer:/u/aDir/ $ echo $DATE
2457470 for March 23, 2016
```

but when I get the value via my logs from yesterday on my Unix machine I have:

```
42447 for March 22,2016
```

(The logs are from my ESQL program)

The question is I need to work with the `rtoday()` value in order to export that value into a flat file (along with other data) in order for other programs to process.

I just need to know how can I get this value in Perl or via the system command line so I can use it.

Comment: I assume your Perl script will be running on the client and connecting to a remote database with DBI or something similar?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot the Perl script will be running on the same server as the database. The same went for the ESQL program

Comment: I think what you need to figure out is the way they calculate their `internal date` (the variable called `i_date` in the example script there.

Comment: [`time()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html) should get the system time in epoch seconds. See if that matches what you get from `rtoday()`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot tried that...it does not match:  username@myserver:/u/myDir $ perl -e "print time()";
1458762740

Comment: That corresponds to Wed Mar 23 13:52:20 2016 in my time zone. What output do you get from `rtoday()`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot i get 42448 in rtoday() for March 23, 2016

Comment: What is the value of the [`DBDATE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBJG3_2.5.0/com.ibm.gen_busug.doc/c_fgl_EnvVariables_DBDATE.htm) environment variable? `rtoday` gets the database's internal representation of the date, so we're comparing apples and oranges here.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot it returns an empty string...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot i think i found it:    Informix ESQL/C supports the SQL DATE data type with the Informix ESQL/C date data type for host variables. The date data type stores internal DATE values. It is implemented as a 4-byte integer whose value is the number of days since December 31, 1899. Dates before December 31, 1899, are negative numbers, while dates after December 31, 1899, are positive numbers. For a complete description of the SQL DATE data type, see the IBM® Informix® Guide to SQL: Reference.

Comment: Ah okay. You can calculate that with the [`delta_days`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#dt-delta_days-datetime) method from the [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) module.

Comment: I'm very puzzled about why you're getting such a different value from me for the date — I get 42451 on 2016-03-23, yet your value is 3 different (42448).  Have you checked the system clock and/or TZ value on you system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual page is from Informix ESQL/C.

You need to know that the date in Informix is the number of days since day 0, which was 1899-12-31 – so day 1 was 1900-01-01.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlhdr.h"

int main(void)
{
    int4 date;
    rtoday(&date);
    printf("%ld\n", date);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this (Informix ESQL/C) program on 2016-03-23, I get the response 42451.  When I tested the SQL:

```
$ sqlcmd -d stores "select date('2016-03-22') - date('1899-12-31')
>                     from informix.systables where tabid = 1"
```

The output was 42450, which is consistent with the ESQL/C program (though `sqlcmd` — the one from the [IIUG](http://www.iiug.org/software/index_ESQLC.html), not Microsoft's recent invention of the same name — is also an ESQL/C program).  It is not consistent with the value shown in the question (42447 for 2016-03-22); I don't know why there's a discrepancy.  Just for the record, I was using ESQL/C 3.70.FC4 (and Informix 11.70.FC4) on RHEL 5 Linux for x86_64 — and with ESQL/C 4.10.FC5 (and Informix 12.10.FC5) on Mac OS X 10.11.4.  I would not expect any difference with ESQL/C 3.50 (Informix 11.50) on any other platform.

The date 1970-01-01 has the ordinal number 25568 using this same scheme.  You could therefore convert a value from `time` to the correct value with:

```
$ perl -le 'print time, " ", int(time/(24*60*60))+25568'               
1458764790 42451
$ perl -le 'sub informix_date_from_unix_time { return int($_[0]/86400) + 25568; }
>           print time, " ", informix_date_from_unix_time(time)'
1458765443 42451
$
```

This is the core answer and is accurate in the UTC time zone; you need to consider carefully about day boundaries and time zones and the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `system` with `echo $DATE` as command?

```
   @args = ("command", "arg1", "arg2");
   system(@args) == 0
        or die "system @args failed: $?"
```

Or you can access environment variables from Perl using `%ENV` hash:

```
$ perl -e 'print $ENV{"DATE"}'
```

Comment: Does not give me the same results as rtoday()

Comment: i get 42448 in rtoday() for March 23, 2016

Answer (score 0):

From the code (pasted below) posted on the IBM website that you are referring to it seems that rtoday() returns *internal representation* of today's date and this representation needs to be formatted with `rdatestr` function. It might mean, that this representation is totally implementation dependent.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   mint errnum;
   char today_date[20];
   int4 i_date;

   printf("RTODAY Sample ESQL Program running.\n\n");

    /* Get todays date in the internal format */
   rtoday(&i_date);

    /* Convert date from internal format into a mm/dd/yyyy string */
   if ((errnum = rdatestr(i_date, today_date)) == 0)
      printf("\n\tTodays date is %s.\n", today_date);
   else
      printf("\n\tError %d in converting date to mm/dd/yyyy\n", errnum);

   printf("\nRTODAY Sample Program over.\n\n");
}
```

Comment: It is an implementation-dependent encoding for dates, but it is machine-independent (and O/S independent) and portable between systems using Informix.  There are support functions for DATE manipulation in the Informix ESQL/C library — such as `rtoday()` and `rdatestr()` and a number of others.

Answer (score 0):

So after some work and the detail definition of what the value I'm looking for I came up with this:

```
#!/opt/standard_perl/perl5881/bin/perl
use Date::Calc qw(:all);


my $date = "03/19/2016";

print getSQLDate($date);

sub getSQLDate
{

my $value = shift;
my @date = split('/', $value);

my $alphaDay = 31;
my $alphaMonth = 12;
my $alphaYear = 1899;

my @alphaDate = ($alphaYear, $alphaMonth,$alphaDay);
my @currentDate = ($date[2], $date[0], $date[1]);
return Delta_Days(@alphaDate, @currentDate);

}
```

my output is:

```
42447
```

I did this based off of this definition that I found about my SQL Date:

> Informix ESQL/C supports the SQL DATE data type with the Informix ESQL/C 
>       date data type for host variables. The date data type stores internal DATE 
>       values. It is implemented as a 4-byte integer whose value is the number of days
>       since December 31, 1899. Dates before December 31, 1899, are negative numbers,
>       while dates after December 31, 1899, are positive numbers. For a complete 
>       description of the SQL DATE data type, see the IBM® Informix® Guide to SQL: 
>       Reference.

Comment: Ahah; you have 2016-03-19 producing 42447; that's consistent with what I'd expect.